# CORS cookie not set in any browser

Tags: javascript, cookies, cors

Response has valid `set-cookie` header, shows up in response inspector and everything:

[image]

But it doesn't set it and therefore doesn't send it with next requests. `window.document.cookie` returns empty string. Setting `path` or `expires` doesn't help, neither does `domain=localhost.com;`.

Starting to lose my mind after 2 days, Im missing something or it's impossible? I've googled **a lot.**

---

## Details:

- No cookie, CORS related errors
- API: `https://abc123.api.api-domain.com/`
- App: `http://www.localhost.com/` (**set in hosts file**, it's actually 127.0.0.1/localhost)

---

#### Response headers:

- `OPTIONS`:

  - Access-Control-Max-Age: `'600'`
  - Access-Control-Allow-Headers: `'Content-Type, Cookie'`
  - Access-Control-Allow-Origin: `'http://www.localhost.com'`
  - Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: `'true'`
  - Access-Control-Allow-Methods: `'OPTIONS, POST'`
- `POST`:

  - Access-Control-Allow-Origin: `'http://www.localhost.com'`
  - Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: `'true'`
  - Set-Cookie: `'customCookie=somehash; domain=.localhost.com;'`

---

#### Fetch function:

```js
return fetch('https://abc123.api.api-domain.com/', {
  method: 'POST',
  credentials: 'include', // to allow cookies
  headers: {
    'content-type': 'application/json'
  },
  body: JSON.stringify(someData),
}).then(res => {
  return res.json();
});
```

---

#### Request headers:

- Host: `"abc123.api.api-domain.com"`
- Origin: `"http://www.localhost.com"`
- Referer: `"http://www.localhost.com/page"`

Comment: @johnny5 For `OPTIONS` right? No. Do I need to expose any? Which ones? I thought that _browser_ can access them anyway, especially cookies.